# Internet Explorer 6 Sending Random GET

Tags: java, session, cookies, internet-explorer-6, java-ee-5

We have a button in our web application that when clicked starts a long running process. Depending on the parameters of this process, the http request sometimes takes a long time to finish. Some http requests take 30 seconds, others 1 minute and others as much as more than 5 minutes.

The problem we are encountering is that after approximately 300 seconds (which is the number I got after several tests) a GET request is sent from IE6 to the browser telling it to invalidate the session by going to this url:

https://ourwebsite.com/portal/jsp/login/logoff.jsp?loginUrl=/portal/jsp/login/login_norm.jsp&sessionInvalidated=true

We are currently looking into our javascript code or on our jsps for possible culprits but we would like to rule out at this point that it might be an issue with the browser.

Is there anything I need to know about IE6 regarding session/connection timeouts?

I did a little research and found out that it has a KeepAliveTimeout of 1 minute as well as a ServerInfoTimeout of 2 minutes. We have http requests that take around 2 minutes and 10 seconds, which is well within range of the 3 minutes that IE has (2 minutes ServerInfoTimeout + 1 minute KeepAlivTimeout).

What happens after this timeout is reached?

Comment: Please please please *please* stop developing sites for IE6. Just let it die. *Please*.

Comment: @Spudley LOL, that's not my call to make.

Answer (score 4):

IE doesn't magically know which URL to GET, your app is setting this, probably in Javascript, probably with a `setTimeout()` call.

Search your web app source for the parameter it uses; `sessionInvalidated` and you'll find out where it is being set.